# Download Image In WebView ios

Tags: ios, wordpress, xcode, image, download-manager

i am making app with Xcode using my Wordpress Site as backend , and I am using WebView , I have download html code in my site , now when i click on download button in ios app it just open full image but not downloading the image, in android app I have code to download image but i don't know how to do this in Xcode , this is my html code in site

```
<a href="http://www.punjabidharti.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/jassi-gill-troll.jpg?" download="Jassi Gill Troll"><img src="http://www.punjabidharti.com/images/download.png" height="25" width="100" /></a>
```

can i download image in Xcode too ?

Answer (score 0):

First Tell Me You use Html page or not if you use html page then use "SwiftSoup library" to get all Extract data which you want. Tis answer only for xcode.

Comment: yes i use html page, how to use "SwiftSoup library" ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not download images automatically (unless you take a screenshot, it gets stored in Photos).

When you see a full size image, tap on it continuously until a pop up like this appears :

[image: Save Image Pop Up]

Then click on save your image will be saved.